# Can we not call a .NET Core API from .NET Framework 4.7

Tags: .net, .net-core, httpclient, restsharp, webapi

I have an API built in .NET Core 3.1. I want to call it from a .NET Framework 4.7 API.

I tried with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{BaseUrl}/{url}", content);
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return result;
```

Then I also tried with RestSharp

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
AddCustomHeaders(ref request);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = await _client.ExecuteAsync<ApiResult<IEnumerable<T>>>(request);
return response.Data;
```

The request got frozen, seems to be stuck.

My assumption is because .NET Core uses `IActionResult` and that is not supported in .NET framework, so that's why it is not interpreting.

So, simple question is why we can not call a .NET Core API from the .NET Framework? Then what is the solution?

Because millions of applications are built using the .NET framework.

It means they can not utilise new .NET Core APIs in their code?

My .NET Core endpoint is

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search/{isRefreshCache}")]
public IActionResult Search(Patient req, bool isRefreshCache)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _patientService.Search(req, isRefreshCache);
        return Ok(ApiResult.Success(result));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        return Ok(ApiResult.Error<string>(ex.Message, (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
    }
}
```

Return type is

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
    public T Output { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int ErrorCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you returning from your API endpoint? Please add it to your post.

Comment: The issue isn't framework compatibility. Your response would serialize to JSON which can obviously be parsed in both .NET Core and .NET Framework. I'd suggest trying an HTTP Debugger like Telerik Fiddler Classic to help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Try calling API with postman see if it is working.

Comment: It is working on postman !

Comment: It is working fine on postman, swagger and thunder client  -  :)

Comment: Based in the symptoms described, and in the integration all headers and arguments are correct specified as on postman or fiddler I have a theory, I think certificate from asp.net is invalid or expired, in that case call get suck.

Comment: I'd try a GET endpoint without parameters. Just to check if connection can be made.

Answer (score 0):

APIs connect to each other by network, they can be written at any language, even Delphi API to ASP.NET Core API. First of all, HttpClient class has Request timeout for stuck requests, does it throw any error? Second, try to debug recieving API. Does it recieve request? Does it deserialize it to params? Does handling code (maybe controller or smth) launches?